# Declaring let identifier in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables

I'm still trying to learn about global and local identifiers on nodejs, but still not clear for me.

I'm trying to use those variables from some query, then use them again with the results from database in page.evaluate().
Someone can help me? I've tried many ways.

```js
let initial_time = null;
let end_time = null;
(async () => {

  const query_time = await query('select time_i, time_f from time_config where config_id = 1', function(err, results) {
    if (err) throw err;
    for (var i in results) {
      var time = results[0];
      initial_time = time['time_i'];
      end_time = time['time_f'];
    }
  })
})
()

const result_time = await page.evaluate(() => {
  return [].concat.apply([], document.querySelectorAll('.ipo-Fixture.ipo-Fixture_Time'))
    .filter(e => {

      const timeString = e.innerText;
      const minute = +timeString.split(':')[0];
      return (minute > initial_time && minute < end_time);
    })
    .map(e => e.innerText);

})
```

Comment: Don't use globals. Pass your data as arguments to your functions instead.

Comment: Thanks @Evert but how to pass those arguments to the next function?

Comment: When you call the function, you pass that variable.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions is to pass the variables to your function something like this

```
(async () => {

const query_time = await query('select time_i, time_f from time_config where config_id = 1', function(err, results){
if(err) throw err;
for (var i in results){
var time = results[0];
var initial_time = time['time_i'];
var end_time = time['time_f'];
}
page.evaluate(initial_time,end_time) 

})  
})
()

const result_time = await page.evaluate(initial_time,end_time,() => {
return [].concat.apply([], document.querySelectorAll('.ipo-Fixture.ipo-Fixture_Time'))
.filter(e => {

const timeString = e.innerText;
const minute = +timeString.split(':')[0];
return (minute > initial_time && minute < end_time);
})
.map(e => e.innerText);

})
```

Comment: Thanks @Sven There's something wrong. TypeError: result_time is not a function

Comment: Thanks @Sven I think now I need to do something in the table because I've created as CHAR and I'm getting this error now. Evaluation failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' So maybe it's getting the char result and getting error because the :

Comment: do you now get the variables in your function ?